# Indexing a 1D tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow

Is it possible to get the element from a tensor at a given index in order to obtain a scalar? For example given an image I can retrieve its shape with `shape = tf.shape(image)`, but how can I retrieve its height, width and depth?

The only way I found is the following:

```
height = tf.reshape(tf.slice(shape, [0], [1]), [])
width = tf.reshape(tf.slice(shape, [1], [1]), [])
depth = tf.reshape(tf.slice(shape, [2], [1]), [])
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slice syntax (i.e. using the `[]` operator) is based on NumPy slicing, and gives a slightly more concise way of getting the height, width and depth from a `shape` tensor:

```
shape = tf.shape(image)
height = shape[0]  # returns a scalar
width = shape[1]   # returns a scalar
depth = shape[2]   # returns a scalar
```

[Nessuno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40343145/3574081) will also work well if the tensor has a statically determined shape. However, variable-sized images (e.g. the result of [`tf.image.decode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_jpeg)) will typically give `None` for the height and width dimensions when you use `get_shape()`, because these may vary from one image to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tf.Variable.get_shape(variable)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable).

```
image = tf.Variable([ [ [1,2,3],[3,4,4],[1,1,1] ], [[1,2,3],[3,4,4],[1,1,1] ]])
shape = image.get_shape()
print( [shape[i].value for i in range(len(shape))] )
```

Outputs:

[2, 3, 3]